# Find the dimension of the set $S=\{B_{6\times 6}: AB=BA\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let , $A_{6\times 6}$ **diagonal** matrix with characteristic polynomial $x(x+1)^2(x-1)^3$. Find the dimension of the set $S=\{B_{6\times 6}: AB=BA\}$.

From characteristic polynomial of $A$ , first we right the matrix as

$$A=\left[\begin{matrix}0&&&&&&&\\&-1&&&&&&\\&&-1&&&&&\\&&&&1&&&\\&&&&&1&&\\&&&&&&1\end{matrix}\right].$$ Then I take $B$ in general form and find $AB$ and $BA$. Then  taking $AB=BA$ and solving we can find $$B=\left[\begin{matrix}a_1&0&0&&&\\0&a_2&a_3&&&\\0&a_4&a_5&&&\\&&& a_ 6 & a_ 7 & a_ 8\\&&& a_ 9 & a_{ 10 } & a_{ 11 }\\&&& a_{ 12 } & a_{ 13 } & a_{ 14 }\end{matrix}\right].$$

So, clearly  $dim(S)=14$.

But it is very lengthy and laborious...

> Are there any other simplest way to find the dimension of $S$ without taking $B$ in general form ?

Comment: notice: $14=1^2+2^2+3^2$.

Comment: Is it hold for any case ?

Comment: Why not try to prove it, S.P?

Comment: First I want to know that is it hold for all case ?(In fact I have a doubt though I am searching for an example to disprove it ) ..If the answer is yes then the question to prove comes..and I will ask to prove.

Comment: No, try to prove it, I mean, in the general case. If you find a proof, you win; if you don't find a proof, you probably find a counterexample while trying.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find such an example...So I think it is TRUE..I tried to prove it but could not prove it..Can you give the proof ??please....

Comment: Have a look at the answer from Omno..., maybe you can see how to generalize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can find the dimension of this space a bit more efficiently by breaking $A$ into block matrices.  In particular, we have
$$
A = \pmatrix{0\\&-I_2\\&&I_3}
$$
Now, an arbitrary $B$ can be written as 
$$
B = \pmatrix{
B_{11} & B_{12} & B_{13}\\
B_{21}& B_{22} & B_{23}\\
B_{31} & B_{32} & B_{33}
}
$$
Where the two matrices have been partitioned in the same way. So, we have
$$
AB = 
\pmatrix{
0 & 0 & 0\\
-B_{21}& -B_{22} & -B_{23}\\
B_{31} & B_{32} & B_{33}
}, \quad
BA =
\pmatrix{
0 & -B_{12} & B_{13}\\
0&  -B_{22} & B_{23}\\
0 & -B_{32} & B_{33}
}
$$
From there, we can quickly reach the desired conclusion.

I believe this is the quickest way to answer the question.

---

We could generalize this into an inductive argument.

Begin with a diagonal matrix $A$.  Then, let
$$
A' = 
\pmatrix{
A & 0\\
0 & cI_k
}
$$
for some $c \in \Bbb C$.  If we want to find the set of matrices $B'$ such that $A'B' = B'A'$, then we could write $B'$ as a block matrix of the form
$$
B' = \pmatrix{B_{11} & B_{12}\\B_{21} & B_{22}}
$$
We then have
$$
A'B' = 
\pmatrix{
AB_{11} & AB_{12}\\
cB_{21} & cB_{22}
}, \quad
B'A' = 
\pmatrix{
B_{11}A & cB_{12}\\
B_{21}A & cB_{22}
} 
$$
We can then conclude that $B_{11}A = AB_{11}$, $B_{12} = 0 = B_{21}$, and $B_{22}$ can be freely chosen.

Now, we can immediately deduce a general form for $S$ as long as $A$ is diagonal.

Comment: See my latest edit for a more general answer.

Comment: Good answer, but you can take this one step further to help the OP find a faster way to get the dimension of $S$. Notice that a block in $B$ which can be freely chosen, such as $B_{22}$, corresponding with the block $cI_k$ in $A$, is the same order as $cI_k$, that is, it is $k \times k$. So the dimension of the space of all such matrices is $k^2$. Now notice that each block $cI_k$ in $A$ comes from a factor $(x-c)^k$ in the characteristic polynomial. So this means if $c(A)=(x-c_1)^{k_1}(x-c_2)^{k_2}\ldots$ then dim$(S)=k_1^2+k_2^2+\cdots$.

Comment: Yes, the $B=B_{11}$ trick is what makes this an "Inductive argument", I guess I never say that explicitly.